# How to add a link to list item in a JSON view format?

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting, column-formatting

Basically I need to find out the item URL to populate the href attribute of an "a" element in a JSON view format (aka rowFormatter) in SharePoint online.
Is there is predefined shortcut for the item URL?

```
     "elmType": "a",
     "attributes": {
       "href": "[$ItemUrl]"
     },
     "txtContent": "CLICK HERE"
```

I made the [$ItemUrl] up, it does not work like this.

Answer (score 5):

You could use $ID.

Sample demo:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {
    "target": "_blank",
    "href": "= @currentWeb + '/ChildB/DispForm.aspx?ID=' + [$ID]"
  }
}
```

Comment: It works but it doesn't new window with selected item, not the right pannel (with or without custom form).

Comment: This URL isn't working for me (404 page not found). I'm working in Sharepoint Online, and the entries I'm trying to link to are modern pages. Is there a variant of this approach that will work?

Answer (score 4):

There is another option that is to just use the **defaultClick** action:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "button",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "defaultClick"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": "ms-fontColor-black ms-fontColor-themePrimary--hover",
    "title": "Open eFolder"
  },
  "style": {
    "border": "none",
    "background-color": "transparent",
    "cursor": "pointer",
    "padding-left": "0px"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "[$Name]"
    }
  ]
}
```

This way you dont need to worry about url string buildup

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {
    "target": "_blank",
    "href": "='/sites/Developer/Lists/ChildB/EditForm.aspx?ID=' + [$ID]"
  }
}
```