# Enable link to document with edit menu option for different column other than Name in document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, document-library, site-column

I've tried [this solution](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53459/change-title-linked-to-item-with-edit-menu-to-different-column) for document library and it is not working for me.

```
<ViewFields><br/>
<FieldRef Name="Attachments"/><br/>
<FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"/><br/>
<FieldRef Name="linkThisColumn" ListItemMenu="TRUE" LinkToItemAllowed="Required" linkToItem="TRUE"/><br/>
<FieldRef Name="data_x0020_column"/><br/>
<FieldRef Name="Another_x0020_column"/><br/>
```

FYI: I am trying to achieve this in modern SharePoint site using SharePoint Designer 2013

Comment: Did you try JSON column formatting. Refer this link - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-column-formatting-display-single-link-of-text-as-hyperlink/

Comment: this too - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/258631/how-to-add-a-link-to-list-item-in-a-json-view-format

Comment: Similar issue post for your reference: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/270679/easy-way-to-add-link-to-item-on-any-column-in-sharepoint-online-list-set-to-mo

Comment: I did try JSON formatting but it won't be useful in my case. I want link to document with edit menu option without creating any new column and in JSON formatting I'll need Link column as we can not create links dynamically (for the .url documents we need hidden links not link to item) in JSON formatting.